# Can I play along to Garageband lessons with an instrument which isn't connected to the computer?

Tags: garageband

When I try launching a piano lesson in GarageBand '11, it says the following:

> **GarageBand has detected that you don to have a musical keyboard attached.**
>
> Please connect your USB or MIDI-compatible keyboard to play along with this lesson.

Obviously there is some benefit to following the lesson with a musical instrument that connects to the computer. Is there any way to get the same result if my piano does not have a way to connect to the computer? For example, I have seen apps that listen to a piano and tell you which keys you are playing. I'm wondering if this kind of technology is built into GarageBand or not.

If there is no way to get the "play along" feature by not plugging in a piano, how much am I being set back in trying to learn the piano? Is there a major benefit to having the "play along" feature? Will I still be able to learn to play the piano in the same amount of time, or is this feature indispensable (e.g. since the immediate feedback is crucial to correct mistakes)?